# Navbar Collapse JQuery not firing - Bootstrap 3.1.1

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, shopify

I know this has been asked many times on SO, however all of the answers I've tried haven't worked.

I want to fire a Mega Menu for a theme built on Bootstrap 3.1.1 and Shopify.

Menu is in place, however, I can't get the menu to collapse! It's just stuck on open at page load.

It's working perfectly on this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/eMEi9T7PgE)

However, on my [staging server](https://montiel-sandbox.myshopify.com/) (Shopify) it's not firing correctly. (PW: `lukeskywalker`)

Header:

```
{{ 'bootstrap.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
{{ 'style.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
```

Markup:

```
<header class="main-header container-fluid">
 <div class="row top-header">

 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
  {% include 'social' %}
 </div>

<div id="utilityNav" class="utility-nav col-sm-6 col-md-6">

    <form id="searchWrapper" class="floatRight" action="/search" method="get">
        <input type="hidden" name="type" value="product" />
        <input id="searchInput" type="text" name="q" placeholder="search..." value="">
        <input id="searchButton" type="submit" value="Search" alt="Search">
    </form><!-- searchWrapper -->

<ul class="user-utility">
    {% if shop.customer_accounts_enabled %}
    {% if customer %}

    <li{% if template contains 'customer' %} class="activePage"{% endif %}><a href="/account" title="Account">Account</a></li>
    <li>{{ "SIGN OUT" | customer_logout_link }}</li>
    {% else %}
    <li{% if template contains 'customer' %} class="activePage"{% endif %}>{{ "SIGN IN" | customer_login_link }} &nbsp;&nbsp; | </li>
    {% endif %}
    {% endif %}

        <li><a href="/cart" id="cartLink">BAG
        {% comment %}{% if shop.customer_accounts_enabled %}<span id="cartLinkBorder">|</span>{% endif %}{% endcomment %}
            <!-- <span id="cartIcon" class="icon-shopping-cart"></span> -->
            <span id="yourCart">{{ cart.item_count }}</span>
        </a>
        </li>
</ul>

    </div><!-- utilityMenu -->
</div> <!-- top header -->

<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".js-navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MegaMenu</a>
</div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse js-navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Collection <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span></a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu row">
                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">New in Stores</li>
                        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                          <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="item active">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/254x150/3498db/f5f5f5/&text=New+Collection" class="img-responsive" alt="product 1"></a>
                                <h4><small>Summer dress floral prints</small></h4>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">49,99 €</button> <button href="#" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Add to Wishlist</button>
                            </div><!-- End Item -->
                            <div class="item">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/254x150/ef5e55/f5f5f5/&text=New+Collection" class="img-responsive" alt="product 2"></a>
                                <h4><small>Gold sandals with shiny touch</small></h4>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">9,99 €</button> <button href="#" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Add to Wishlist</button>
                            </div><!-- End Item -->
                            <div class="item">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/254x150/2ecc71/f5f5f5/&text=New+Collection" class="img-responsive" alt="product 3"></a>
                                <h4><small>Denin jacket stamped</small></h4>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">49,99 €</button> <button href="#" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Add to Wishlist</button>
                            </div><!-- End Item -->
                          </div><!-- End Carousel Inner -->
                        </div><!-- /.carousel -->
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">View all Collection <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right pull-right"></span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Dresses</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Unique Features</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Image Responsive</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Auto Carousel</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Newsletter Form</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Four columns</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Tops</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Good Typography</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Jackets</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Easy to customize</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Glyphicons</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Pull Right Elements</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Pants</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Coloured Headers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Primary Buttons & Default</a>  </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Calls to action</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Accessories</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Default Navbar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lovely Fonts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Responsive Dropdown </a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Newsletter</li>
                        <form class="form" role="form">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
                          </div>
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
                        </form>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </li>
    </ul>

</div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
</nav>
</div>





</header><!-- mainHeader -->
```

Comment: I test this here and totally works for me, you need try remove one by one <link> and <script> to understand how the menu is already opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS code on your style.css file you have:

```
.main-header ul, li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

This is overwriting your `.mega-dropdown-menu` which has the `display:none;` which is why your menu is always showing.

Unfortunately even when I changed that your menu didnt seem to work. I noticed that on the bootply example when you click to open the menu the DOM would update with a 'open' (showing next to the `dropdown-menu` class) class and a `before` and `after` pseudo would be added as well which doesnt seem to be happening on your site.

Comment: I think this is the most likely problem, the CSS overriding. I wonder if i fix that .`main-header ul` it may update the DOM issue?

Comment: If I were you I would try to test your site without any of your custom CSS or JS to see if you can get the menu to work with out it and then add back in elements one at a time to see what is causing the conflict.

Comment: This led me to comment out: `.main-header.container-fluid` and `.main-header ul, li` and it works! ;)

Answer (score 1):

@crazymatt is correct, that style is causing your nav to stay open in desktop view, though that alone did not fix the open menu in mobile.

If you add the following style to the mobile breakpoint, the mobile menu will work as well.

```
.in .dropdown-menu {
   display: block;
}
```

I also noticed that on your live environment you are calling the jQuery and bootstrap libraries twice. I don't believe it is causing this nav issue, but it would be a good idea to remove those duplicates. There is an instance of both in the header and another set in the footer (loaded by shopify).